# Installation problems with MS SQL server for linux

Tags: server, package-management, dependencies

I have run into a problem installing mssql server (ver. 14.0.600) on an Ubuntu server (16.04, x86-64). The installation stops with the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mssql-server : Depends: openssl (<= 1.1.0).
```

However, `apt-cache policy openssl` reports
openssl as:

```
Installed: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 /
Candidate: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4
```

sudo apt-get install -f was initially: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded`.
After apt-get upgrade (apache,openssl,grub): `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

Sadly enough, same dependency error as before.

Is openssl 1.1.0f > 1.1.0 ?
Is there any way out of this problem, short of reinstalling Ubuntu with openssl 1.0.2g ?

Trying to downgrade openssl does not appear to be a safe procedure according to several posts on the net.

Edit:    `apt-get purge --auto-remove openssl`
returns `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 139 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
This is not something that I want to/dare to do right now.

Comment: Would you please open a terminal and execute `sudo apt-get -f install` and paste the results of that command into your question?

Comment: This question is also used to solve **UBUNTU 18 LTS** env installation for MS-SQL-Server, see bellow https://askubuntu.com/a/1033154/439867

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem after update openssl, try this

1. Install aptitute `sudo apt install aptitude`
2. `sudo aptitude install mssql-server`

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: openssl (<= 1.1.0) but 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:

```
        1)  mssql-server [Not Installed]
```

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

3. type **n** and press enter

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Downgrade the following packages:

```
        1)  openssl [1.1.0f-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (now) -> 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6 (xenial-security)]
```

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  openssl

4. type **Y** and press enter, and mssql-server will be installed
5. `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`

re-configure your installation

Comment: I had the same trouble, it doesn't show me the option to downgrade, I can't even downgrade using `sudo apt-get install openssl=1.0.2` because it says `E: Version '1.0.2' for 'openssl' was not found
`, I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12):

Apparent solution for Ubuntu 18.04:

```
apt-get install -y libjemalloc1 libsss-nss-idmap0 libc++1 gawk curl

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"

add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list)"

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20160104ubuntu1_all.deb

dpkg -i ca-certificates_20160104ubuntu1_all.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb

dpkg -i openssl_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb

apt install -y libcurl3

apt-get update
apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

It is necessary to check if SQL subsequently works well without problems.

Comment: I am using fresh UBUNTU 18 LTS at digitalOcean droplet and all script runs fine (!). After all, the last messages was *"Please run `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` to complete the setup of Microsoft SQL Server"* and after it *"...  Please run `systemctl restart mssql-server.service`."*

`

Comment: FYI [Installing SQL Server 2017 for Linux on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/installing-sql-server-2017-for-linux-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) - by the SQL Server engineering team.